# Qt.labs.plarform is not installed only in release mode

Tags: qt, import, qml, qtquick2

I am using FileDialog from Qt.labs.platform 1.1 on win 10 in Qt creator, compilator I use is Desktop Qt 5.15.2. MinGW 64 bit.
In the debug mode is working everthing fine but when I change to release mode I get following error in from the compilator:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:6:1: module "Qt.labs.platform" is not installed

I tried things like clean and rebuild or restart the computer and also change the number of import version but nothing helps. Any ideas how to solve that, please?

Comment: Do you have a qtlabsplatformplugin.dll file in the qml\Qt\labs\platform directory within your Qt installation? You can also set the `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` environment variable to `1` before running the application to see where it tries to load it from.

Comment: Yes, I have qtlabsplatformplugin.dll there. I am not sure how to set environment variable, I add the line in the .pro file but nothing happened.
Finally I used QtQuick.Dialogs import where is the FileDialog little different but works for my purposes. I came to the lab version through the Qt Creator help, where one finds unfortunately only the FileDialog from Qt.labs.platform which is evidently not working properly.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-settings-environment.html

Answer (score 1):

Install `qml-module-qt-labs-platform` if using Debian or a derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Check folder, where you are building your release (where *.exe is generated):
does it contains some Qt's *.dll's?
If yes: there is two ways to resolve your problem:

1. Remove all Qt *.dll's and run your application from Qt Creator (then Qt Creator will take all Qt *.dll's from folder, where Qt is installed).
2. Or add all needed Qt *.dll's with correct folder structure to folder with your release *.exe (to do it for Windows release use windeployqt tool: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html )

Why you have such error from the compilator?
Because you have some Qt *.dll's in your release folder (beside the *.exe), but not all needed (e.g. you have only Qt6Core.dll). So Qt Creator will find this dll and will try to find other dll's in your release folder. Qt Creator will not check its installation directory to get dll's.
But if you have no Qt *.dll's in your release folder, then Qt Creator will find them in its installation directory.